# Read Outlook messages in ASP.NET catches out of bounds error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, outlook, ms-office, integration

I am trying to integrate MS outlook in asp.net. My code(below) catches out of bounds error. What am I doing wrong? am I not getting the inbox messages properly? Thanks in advance

EDIT: based on my debugging
`inbox = name.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)`
Returns nothing. I am not sure why

```
 Dim ol As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
        Dim name As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace
        Dim inbox As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim item As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PostItem
        Dim subF As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder

        Try
            name = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            name.Logon(Nothing, Nothing, False, False)
            inbox = name.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
            subF = inbox.Folders(0)
            Dim ctr As Integer
            For ctr = 0 To subF.Items.Count
                item = subF.Items(ctr)
                Label1.Text += "Subject: " + item.Subject + "<br/>"
                Label1.Text += "Date: " + item.SentOn.ToLongDateString() + " " + item.SentOn.ToLongTimeString() + "<br/>"
                Label1.Text += "Category: " + item.Categories + "<br/>"
                Label1.Text += "Body: " + item.Body + "<br/>"
                Label1.Text += "HtmlBody: " + item.HTMLBody + "<br/>"


            Next



        Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### Check your index base

Change

```
For ctr = 0 To subF.Items.Count
```

to

```
For ctr = 1 To subF.Items.Count
```

Or possibly to

```
For ctr = 0 To subF.Items.Count - 1
```

...if Microsoft finally got rid of the base-1-indexing scheme with the Outlook objects.

---

### Make sure there's actually a folder!

Check to ensure that the inbox contains subfolders.  If not, use the inbox itself.

```
inbox = name.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
If inbox.Folders.Count > 0 Then
    subf = inbox.Folders(1)
Else
    subf = inbox
End If
```

Comment: inbox = name.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) returns nothing dunno why